# override beforeunload dialog?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, onbeforeunload

My backbone View:

```
module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
...
  initialize(options) {
    $(window).on('beforeunload', () => {
      if ( _.isEqual(_.sortBy(currentStates), _.sortBy(this._savedStates)) === false ) {
        return 'Unsaved queries.';
      }
    });
  },
...
```

My goal is to check unsaved data and notify users before leaving some pages.

1, But one issue, on firefox, it will not show my message (in the code, 'Unsaved queries.').

[image]

2, **Another issue is that how to do if users disable the popup.** The second issue is more important to me now. How to make the popup shown anyway?

3, How to override the behaviour after user clicked "Stay on Page" and "Leave Page" buttons on the above image?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I read some similar posts on stackoverflow. It is difficult. I just wonder there is any way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Short: *1.* you ran into this [ancient bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=641509), your code is OK. *2.* No way, consider adding some GUI element that will indicate there are unsaved changes or auto save content (perhaps with a autosave flag to another table/column) or auto save into the local storage if feasable. *3.* Not possible. If the user clicks "stay on page" your application will still be alive so that uses may save manually, otherwise the user decided to discard the data. Hint: you may try to update your GUI in that handler, perhaps it shows underneath

Comment: Apart from this: your question is not [tag:backbone.js] related.